# Conditions in Expect script causing it to hang

Tags: bash, expect

I'm using an expect script (within a bash script) to ssh into a remote server and execute a script, the local server will know that the remote server's script is finished as it (remote) will echo "finished" at the end of execution.

However, the script can be in one of three locations, so I've designed the following expect script, although in the code example it successfully executes the remote server script - it's unable to detect the printed "finished" and consequently hangs.

Local Server Expect Script:

```
versionScriptLoc1="/path/to/script1"
versionScriptLoc2="/path/to/script2"
versionScriptLoc3="/path/to/script3"
expect <<-EOS |& tee logfile.${hostname}.log
        #!/usr/bin/expect
        set timeout $EXP_TIMEOUT
        puts "\nLogging into remote host via SSH..\n"
        spawn ssh -q -tt -o ConnectTimeout=$SSH_TIMEOUT -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null ${hostname}
        expect "*assword*"
        send -- "$secret\r"
        expect {
                "*assword*" {
                        send \x03
                        puts "\nIncorrect Password\n"
                        exit 1
                }
                "$prompt" {
                        send -- "/usr/seos/bin/sesu - $user\r"
                        expect "*assword*"
                        send -- "$secret\r"
                        expect "$prompt"
                        send -- "${versionScriptLoc1}\r"
                        expect {
                                "finished" {

                                }
                                "No such file or directory" {
                                        puts "Location 1 execution Failed"
                                        send -- "${versionScriptLoc2}\r"
                                        expect {
                                                "No such file or directory" {
                                                        puts "Location 2 execution Failed"
                                                        send -- "${versionScriptLoc3}\r"
                                                }
                                        }
                                        exp_continue
                                }
                        }
                        send -- "exit\r"
                        expect "$prompt"
                        send -- "exit\r"

                }
        }
        expect eof
        exit 0
EOS
```

I thought exp_continue would make the expect loop and look for "finished". In the above code, the script is located in location 2, it sucessfully triggers but even though "finished" is printed, it still hangs.

Any help in why it's hanging/ potentially a better design would be highly appreciated.

PS: I know I should be spawning the scripts instead of triggering them like a user, but I've tried in the past and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you don't write your expect code so deeply nested.

The problem is that, after running script2, you hit the exp_continue whether
you're successful or not. Too bad expect doesn't have an `exp_break` or a
`goto`.

So a bit of restructuring is needed. I'm using some boolean variables to
manage the control flow.

Since I've introduces some Tcl variables, it will make separating the shell
vars from the tcl vars more difficult. We'll turn the shell vars into
environment vars, and quote the heredoc:

```sh
# ...
export EXP_TIMEOUT SSH_TIMEOUT
export hostname user secret prompt
export versionScriptLoc1 versionScriptLoc2 versionScriptLoc3

expect <<'EOS' 2>&1 | tee "logfile.${hostname}.log"

    set timeout $env(EXP_TIMEOUT)
    puts "\nLogging into remote host via SSH..\n"

    spawn ssh -q -tt -o ConnectTimeout=$env(SSH_TIMEOUT) -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null $env(hostname)
    expect "*assword*"
    send -- "$env(secret)\r"

    expect {
        "*assword*" {
            send \x03
            puts "\nIncorrect Password\n"
            exit 1
        }
        "$env(prompt)"
    }

    send -- "/usr/seos/bin/sesu - $env(user)\r"
    expect "*assword*"

    send -- "$env(secret)\r"
    expect "$env(prompt)"

    set run2 false
    send -- "$env(versionScriptLoc1)\r"
    expect {
        "No such file or directory" {
            puts "Location 1 execution Failed"
            set run2 true
        }
        "finished"
    }

    set run3 false
    if {$run2} {
        send -- "$env(versionScriptLoc2)\r"
        expect {
            "No such file or directory" {
                puts "Location 2 execution Failed"
                set run3 true
            }
            "finished"
        }
    }

    if {$run3} {
        send -- "$env(versionScriptLoc2)\r"
        expect {
            "No such file or directory" {
                puts "Location 3 execution Failed"
            }
            "finished"
        }
    }

    send -- "exit\r"
    expect "$env(prompt)"

    send -- "exit\r"

    expect eof
    exit 0
EOS
```